# RabbitVCS displaying unchanged files on commit

Tags: 11.10, svn, rabbitvcs

I have a strange problem with RabbitVCS.

I'm inside a working copy directory and I want to commit some files. When I click the commit button, the commit window shows up, but there is a strange situation. Even though I have modified just a few files, the commit window is displaying all the files and directories inside working copy and the checkbox is ticked for each of them, like those files need to be committed. But those files were not changed and already exist in the repo.

Please see the image below to understand what I'm saying (the only file that is unversioned/was changed is .htaccess, therefore it should have been the only file listed there).

[image]

Has this happened to anyone ? It is a bug with RabbitVCS (and probably a solution exists) or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is ...

- Your VCS tracks the executable flag, and you are using a Windows file system on Linux

Because Windows has no exe bit, when you mount a Windows FS in Linux, by default, every file is marked executable. Because the files were not originally checked in as executable, this shows up as a change to the properties on every file.

You can counteract this by checking out the working copy to a native Linux file system that supports the executable bit, or by altering the way you are mounting the Windows file system by including the `noexec` option. Note that this will prevent anything on this file system being run as a program.

Comment: I think this was the problem, because I did a fresh checkout straight on the linux partition (not a mounted one) and everything seems to be fine. Thanks!